# annotating methods in implementation classes or interfaces?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am using Java1.7 and spring3.

I have below classes.

### MyInterface.java

```
public interface MyInterface{

  String getResult();

}
```

### MyInterfaceImpl.java

```
public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface{

  @MyCustomAnnotation
  public String getResult(){
  //some logic

   }

}
```

I annotated method in Impl class. Is it good practice to annotate methods in implementation class? Or do i need to annotate methods in the interface itself?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends what do you want to achieve. Could you explain what your use-case is?

Comment: My use case is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281470/extracting-the-annotation-value-using-java-reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes don't inherit the annotation from interfaces, so you should be really careful using annotations on interfaces.

Here is an example of what can happen if you are not careful:

http://kim.saabye-pedersen.org/2013/05/spring-annotation-on-interface-or-class.html

Comment: Arnaud then could you plz suggest me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281470/extracting-the-annotation-value-using-java-reflection